# How to get access to authorized user from api inside laravel eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have custom attribute which I must show only authorized users with specific roles:

```
protected $appends = ['count'];

public function getCountAttribute()
{
    $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
    if($user && $user->hasAnyRole(['company', 'editor'])) {        
        $unmoderated = $this->jobs()->where('status', 0)->count();
        $active = $this->jobs()->where('status', 1)->count();
        $closed = $this->jobs()->where('status', 2)->count();
        return [
            'all' => $unmoderated + $active + $closed,
            'unmoderated' => $unmoderated,
            'active' => $active,
            'closed' => $closed
        ];
    }
}
```

This code every time return `null` on result. Because can't see authorized user from API with Laravel Passport. By default from controllers we can access to authorized user from API by adding middleware:

```
->middleware('auth:api')
```

But how I can do it inside model?

Comment: You can use the global auth and the global request methods, like: auth()->user() and request()->user()

Answer (score 0):

you can directly pass guard in helper method

```
$user = auth('api')->user();
```

Or Facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
Auth::guard('api')->user();
```